# Read express session cookie from React js app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, session-cookies

I'm building a project with authentication. I'm using Node+React. I set an express session cookie on the back-end and I want a component in react to read that cookie to see if the user is authenticated or not. For some reason I can not access that cookie from the react(client-side)... Maybe someone could help out?

```js
BACK:
app.use(session({
  name: process.env.SESS_NAME,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: process.env.SESS_SECRET,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: parseInt(process.env.SESS_LIFETIME),
    sameSite: true, //strict,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
  }
}))

FRONT:
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
...
console.log("cookie", Cookies.get("sid"));
```

I have a cookie named "sid" in this case and I can see it in my console in the browser... but when I try to access it its undefiend

[image]
thanks!

Comment: Are you serving the react app from your express instance?

Comment: no I use the server side as api for the client side... @Chev

Comment: is there a specific reason for trying to access it? you've set it as HTTPcookie so you won't be able to access it on the client.
https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you have not set the `httpOnly` property on the cookie when configuring session. The default value is `true` which will prevent client browsers from reading the cookie.

```
Note be careful when setting this to true, as compliant clients will not allow client-side JavaScript to see the cookie in document.cookie.
```

```
app.use(session({
  name: process.env.SESS_NAME,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: process.env.SESS_SECRET,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: parseInt(process.env.SESS_LIFETIME),
    sameSite: false, // this may need to be false is you are accessing from another React app
    httpOnly: false, // this must be false if you want to access the cookie
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
  }
}))
```

See the [cookie options in docs](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/session.html)

Comment: YES but I do want it to be httpOnly since I don't want attackers to have any access... but still I need that for my front-end to know when user is authenticated @Chev

Comment: OK, but your question and answer above explain why you **cannot access the cookie**. You may be confusing session state with authentication and the session cookie is not used to test for authentication. This would be best served using JWT tokens. There are numerous articles on authentication with JWT and recommend you look at the [jsonwebtoken](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken).

Comment: @hindi1991 please can you accept the answer covering why you could not read the cookie so other users can understand. Please create a new question if you having issues with the auth JWT design. Best, Chev